# ¿Como eliminar un conjunto de palabras con python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Gusto en saludarles y de antemano muchas gracias por su repuesta y atención.

Como verán soy padawan en esto y hoy me encontré con un problema la cual bien si le encontré una solución simple, pero confió en que puede mejorar.

**Contexto:**

Como proyecto decidí crear un scrapper para un user bot de telegram, básicamente este lo que hace es obtener actualizaciones de estadísticas y variaciones económicas de paises que proporcionan otros canales telegram.
Por ser varios canales, sus mensajes pueden variar, de este modo decidí editar el mensaje y obtener solo esos datos que necesito (esos número de altos y bajos de las estadísticas)

**Mi Solución:**

Este fue el código que implemente donde "Datos_Canal" semeja el mensaje obtenido en x canales de telegram en este ejemplo son 2 canales distintos:

```
Datos_Canal_1 = "Así vario el D0lar en Argentina esta semana: -  ⬇ 1,53%"
Datos_Canal_2 = "D0lar variación semanal Colombia: - ⬆️ 12,86%"
```

**Código que uso para filtar:**

```
result_1 = Datos_Canal_1.split("*")[-1].split("%")[0]
result_2 = Datos_Canal_2.split("*")[-1].split("%")[0]
```

*Como pueden notar, uso de referencia - y % para obtener solamente los resultados de las estadísticas y personalizar el mensaje que se envía.*

**Optimización:**
Por ahora no conozco método más eficiente de realizar esta tarea, desearía que me orientaran a mejorar y aprender un poco más al respecto.

**Nota:**
Soy nueva en esto de python 3.x, sería muy útil para mí una repuesta no tan técnica nivel Dios por así decirlo jaja, ya que veces no entiendo del todo este lenguaje.

**Objetivo:**

Como son varios canales, los mensajes varían donde por ejemplo al principio el mensaje comienza con la fecha, algunos otros con fecha y hora, arrojan otros datos irrelevantes para mí.

Y mi objetivo es tomar solo esos números de las estadísticas semanales y que el código funcione para distintos canales con diferentes tipos de mensajes.

Comment: He estado pensando una alternativa que requiera menos aprendizaje que el regex, pero requieren o algo tecnico o un código pesado de interpretar. Yo te recomiendo que uses la respuesta de Candid y te pongas a aprender regex y estudiar la suya. Tal y como veo que estás trabajando, creo que te va a servir de mucho.

Answer (score 3):

La características común a los mensajes es que todos incluyen una cifra del tipo 9,99%, que sería la variación del dólar.

Lo más conveniente es usar expresiones regulares, ya que puedo buscar esa cifra descartando todo los demás, sin importar lo que sea.

La expresión regular que te sirve es `r"([\d,]+)%"`. Esta expresión *reconoce* una secuencia de caracteres que sean dígitos o coma, todo eso seguido de "%".

Por eficiencia compilamos la expresión regular primero:

```
import re
patron = re.compile(r"([\d,]+)%")
```

Luego podemos usar el patrón para revisar si el patrón se encuentra en el texto:

```
resultado = patron.search(Datos_Canal_1)
if resultado:
    valor_dolar = resultado.group(1)  # valor como cadena.
    print(valor_dolar)
```

Si `patron` encuentra el valor buscado, devuelve un `Match Object` que nos dara la información necesaria; si no, retorna `None`.

El objeto `resultado` tiene una lista `group` donde guarda las partes del texto que calzan con el patrón. En este caso tenemos sólo un texto, que viene siendo el elemento uno de la lista (el elemento cero es todo el texto que calzó).

#### Demo

Para demo hice una pequeña función que toma el mensaje, extrae el valor y lo retorna como float.

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"([\d,]+)%")

def obtener_valor(mensaje):
    resultado = patron.search(mensaje)
    if resultado:
        valor = resultado.group(1).replace(",", ".")
        return float(valor)
    else:
        return None

tests = [
    "",
    "No hay info",
    "Así vario el D0lar en Argentina esta semana: -  ⬇ 1,53%",
    "D0lar variación semanal Colombia: - ⬆️ 12,86%",
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, '->', obtener_valor(test))
```

produce

```
 -> None
No hay info -> None
Así vario el D0lar en Argentina esta semana: -  ⬇ 1,53% -> 1.53
D0lar variación semanal Colombia: - ⬆️ 12,86% -> 12.86

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @chipping estaba pensando en darte una respuesta y te iba a decir, entre otras cosas, lo que que podrías intentar aprender a usar regex para lograr más facilmente y con menos margen de error lo que buscas. De todas formas, trabajar con el lenguaje natural usando expresiones *regulares* no siempre funciona bien.

Comment: Reconozco que es bueno tener una expresión regular simple. Es más, mi propuesta no es cambiarla, pero si está buena de tener en cuenta. Considero que esta encaja mejor en el escenario: `\d+,\d+%` lee uno o más numeros, seguidos de una coma, seguidos de uno o más numeros, seguidos de un "%". En lugar de `([\d,]+)%`, que coincide con algo como "123,45,,,678%" (no creo que haya mensajes tan desprolijos en esos bots, pero a tener en cuenta).

Comment: Hola Dante, probare como funciona, ya que como indico. 
son varios datos que arroja y muchos de estos van seguidos de un %  porque aparte de la variación semanal, dan la variación mensual entre muchos otros datos aparte del d0lar.

Comment: Igual muchísimas gracias, intento es aprender y desde ahora me pondré a aprender algo de regex. 

Esto de las expresiones regulares me pondré a practicar mucho.

Comment: Suerte chipping! Puedo preguntarte algo no relacionado a la programación? Se te da bien hablar?